# How to show full Name Live agent name in sales force?

Tags: liveagent

I couldn't fill agent name in Live chat Button because we need full name to display in client side from chatting conversation page. I tried, for example,  Full name is "Rajesh Kumar", but the button shows "Rajesh K". Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Salesforce shows First Name and the first letter of Agent's Last Name. You can customise it by going to:

Live Agent Configurations > Edit next to *your configuration*

In **Custom Agent Name** you can use merge fields (which is not that obvious when you look at the layout and field's help text), so in your scenario it would be: **{!User_FullName}**

Comment: Can we display agent name at customer What’s app chat